# Ajax POST Using Ajax Codeigniter Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to explain first ...

I have two domain .. www.one.com and www.two.com

First domain www.one.com 
Form input here

```
<div class="hidden cswrap2">
  <h3>Edit Data Mustahik</h3>
  <div class="cscontent">
    <ul class="cslist">
      <li id="">
      <form  action="javascript:void(0);" name="editmustahik">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: 230px;">  
            <label>Kuantitas</label>
            <input type="text" name="kuantitas" value="<?php echo @$mpzis['kuantitas'];?>" style="width:230px;">
            <input type="text" name="nik" value="<?php echo @$mpzis['nik'];?>" style="width:230px;">
            <input type="text" name="amil_email" value="<?php echo @$mpzis['email_amil'];?>" style="width:230px;">
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="csbutton">
    <input type="button" name="buttonstatus" onclick="hideCustomStatus('cswrap2');" value="Batal" id="customstatusbutton">&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" onclick="UpdateDataMustahik();" value="Update">
  </div>
 </div>
```

this ajax post

```
function UpdateDataMustahik() {
    var formData = $('form[name="editmustahik"]').serialize();

    displayCustomStatus('Update Data Mustahik');
    addCustomStatusContent('Updating Data','update777');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'www.two.com/api_controller/update',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData,
      success: statusUpdate
    });
}

function statusUpdate(json) {
  if(json.status_code == '000') {
      addCustomStatusContent('Sukses','update777');
    }
}
```

i have second domain to direct there .. 
www.two.com/api_controller/update  --> 
url: 'www.two.com/api_controller/update',

in controller i was put this code

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

but still not working ..
error display is 404 not found ..

may you know how to solve this ..

Thanks

Comment: in constructor ?

Comment: yess there --->> public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

Comment: in second domain ---> www.two.com

Comment: put crossDomain:true, after data parameter in ajax request. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check after putting that header code in common page which loaded first. Something like. CI=> index.php

Comment: @user1544541 not working ..

Comment: You can use CURL which works for cross domain

Comment: @RanaGhosh not working

Comment: @MayankPandeyz if  i using CURL where i put the code ? controller? do you have refference?

Comment: In that case your ajax will call controller function and that controller function use CURL and get the response and return it to you.

Comment: i found this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814 .. put on library .. i dont know exactly ..

Comment: how @MayankPandeyz ???

Comment: how @MayankPandeyz give me advice ?

Comment: Have you ever used CURL?

Comment: yes.. wait i try .. i just connect

Comment: because CURL i ever do before in php native .. not in codeigniter

Comment: whats wromg with my code .. i must using CURL ? @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138582/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-tara).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $.ajax({
            url: url
            //dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {data:data},
            success: function (data) {
//your code
} });
```